# Get Json column difference by C#

Tags: c#, json

I have 2 Json files with same structure and I would like to compare the difference between two files. I expect to get the column name only. For example:
Json 1:

```
{
  "Test": [
    {
      "Cust-no": "00000001",
      "Cust-status": "555",
      "Last-update": "1999-08-17"
    }
  ]
}
```

Json 2:

```
{
  "Test": [
    {
      "Cust-no": "00000001",
      "Cust-status": "666",
      "Last-update": "2018-08-17"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected result:

```
[
  "Cust-status",
  "Last-update"
]
```

Comment: And what code do you have to accomplish this?

Comment: So you need to deserialize it and write comparison code?

Comment: Use Json.Net deserializer to conver Json contents to standard C# classes and compare the theme

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json1 = "{  \"Test\": [ { \"Cust-no\": \"00000001\", \"Cust-status\": \"555\", \"Last-update\": \"1999-08-17\" } ]}";
            var json2 = "{  \"Test\": [ { \"Cust-no\": \"00000001\", \"Cust-status\": \"666\", \"Last-update\": \"2018-08-17\" } ]}";
            var list1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json1);
            var list2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json2);

        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        [JsonProperty("Cust-no")]
        public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Cust-status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Last-update")]
        public string LastUpdated { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Test> Test { get; set; }
    }
```

You may now compare the list1 and list2 objects to get the desired output.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

using `Newtonsoft` lib you can do it easily. there is a `JObject` thats like as anonymous object in C#. you can convert you json string to JObject, and then you can loop your JObject properties and check if they are same or not.

Of course you can create C# poco classes and covert your json to the class like Praneet mentioned below, and then do compare manually.

Check the below fiddle. https://dotnetfiddle.net/VCBhCA

```
public static void Main()
{
    var json1 = @"{'Test':[{ "+
                    "'Cust-no':'00000001', "+
                    "'Cust-status':'555', "+
                    "'Last-update':'1999-08-17'} "+ 
                    "]}";

    var json2 = @"{'Test':[{ "+
                    "'Cust-no':'00000001', "+
                    "'Cust-status':'666', "+
                    "'Last-update':'2018-08-17'} "+ 
                    "]}";

    JObject obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json1);
    JObject obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json2);

    if (JToken.DeepEquals(obj1, obj2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Both Objects are same.");
        return;
    }


    // create another JObject thats points to your actual first element in 'Test' node from your json.
    JObject obj1Data = obj1.GetValue("Test")[0] as JObject;
    JObject obj2Data = obj2.GetValue("Test")[0] as JObject;

    var lst = new List<string>();               

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> obj1Prop in obj1Data)
    {
      JProperty obj2Prop = obj2Data.Property(obj1Prop.Key);
      if (!JToken.DeepEquals(obj1Prop.Value, obj2Prop.Value))
      {
          lst.Add(obj1Prop.Key);
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} property value is changed", obj1Prop.Key));
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} property value didn't change", obj1Prop.Key));
      }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nProperty Changed - ");
    lst.ForEach(p=>Console.WriteLine(p));       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code that is not related to any structure of json:

```
class Program
{
    static JArray _ja = new JArray();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json1 = "{  \"Test\": [ { \"Cust-no\": \"00000001\", \"Cust-status\": \"555\", \"Last-update\": \"1999-08-17\" } ]}";
        var json2 = "{  \"Test\": [ { \"Cust-no\": \"00000001\", \"Cust-status\": \"666\", \"Last-update\": \"2018-08-17\" } ]}";
        var jObject1 = JObject.Parse(json1);
        var jObject2 = JObject.Parse(json2);
        CompareJObjects(jObject1, jObject2);


        Console.WriteLine(_ja.ToString());
    }

    static void CompareJObjects(JObject o1, JObject o2)
    {
        foreach (var prop in o1.Properties())
        {
            switch (prop.Value)
            {
                case JValue jv:
                    {
                        CompareJValues((JValue)prop.Value, (JValue)o2[prop.Name], prop.Name);
                        break;
                    }
                case JArray ja:
                    {
                        int arrIndex = 0;
                        foreach (JObject content in ja.Children<JObject>())
                        {
                            CompareJObjects(content, ((JArray)o2[prop.Name]).Children<JObject>().ToList()[arrIndex]);
                            arrIndex++;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case JObject jo:
                    {
                        CompareJObjects(jo, (JObject)o2[prop.Name]);
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void CompareJValues(JValue jv1, JValue jv2, string propName)
    {
        var o1PropValue = jv1.Value;
        var o2PropValue = jv2.Value;
        if (!o1PropValue.Equals(o2PropValue))
        {
            _ja.Add(new JValue(propName));
        }
    }

}
```

It uses `Newtonsoft.Json` the most popular `json` library for `.net`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your json contains list like below

```
{
  "Test": [
    {
      "Cust-no": "00000001",
      "Cust-status": "555",
      "Last-update": "1999-08-17"
    },
    {
      "Cust-no": "00000002",
      "Cust-status": "556",
      "Last-update": "1999-08-18"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use below code for reading

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"other.json"))
{
                var json = r.ReadToEnd();
                var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
}
```

It will give you results like below

[image]

Once you get the data in two objects for two files using linq you can compare the results